# grails ui plugin not working with grails 2.1.0

Tags: grails, yui, grails-plugin

I wanted to test some of the features like expandablePannels etc before putting into another project, so I created a new project with a CRUD just so I can use grails ui

I am using Intellij 11, so I installed the plugin and was responded with the following error:

```
Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:yui:[2.6.0,)


IDEA hook: Grails not found!
| Error java.lang.NullPointerException
| Error     at org.jetbrains.groovy.grails.rt.Agent$2.run(Agent.java:99)
| Error     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Anyone else having issues using this plugin ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yet easier:

Edit BuildConfig.groovy and change the lines of the plugin dependency by these:

```
compile ":yui:2.8.2.1"
    compile (":grails-ui:1.2.3") {
         excludes 'yui'
    }
```

Just in case it's useful to you.

Comment: Not sure why this is not up-voted as it does work and is a lot cleaner than the other solution: this is a change in the source tree which can be checked in as opposed to fiddling with files in your $HOME/.grails folder...

Comment: I agree, this is much cleaner way to do it. Upvoted it too. @yan - This is an old question, and the cleaner answer came way after it had been addressed in Grails configuration's documentation(I may be wrong & might have skipped reading it actually). Tht's y it's not upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into same problem while upgrading my app from grails 1.3.7 to 2.1.0. yui is a dependency for grails-ui plugin (as grails-ui needs bubbling, and bubbling needs yui :-/) This is what I did :

1. Goto .grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugin/grails-ui folder
2. Open the file ivy-(version).xml (ivy-1.2.3.xml)
3. Look for this line : `<dependency org="org.grails.plugins" name="yui" rev="**[2.6.0,)**" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)">`
4. Replace [2.6.0,) with 2.8.2, so final line will look like this : `<dependency org="org.grails.plugins" name="yui" rev="2.8.2" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)">`
5. grails clean and grails compile

After this, this error was gone for good.
Hope this helps.

### UPDATE :

Thanks to predicador37 ; Much cleaner & groovy-way of doing this - Put this under plugins in BuildConfig.groovy :

```
compile ":yui:2.8.2.1"
compile (":grails-ui:1.2.3") {
     excludes 'yui'
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I had to create a new project as it still kept on complaining about rev 2.6.0, but it seems as though I can use it !
Really appreciate it, having the same kind of problem with RichUI 0.9 now :'(

Comment: @Ryan, There were two important points in the [grails upgrade guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html) 1) Some plugins may fail to install because one or more of their dependencies can not be found. If this happens, the plugin probably has a custom repository URL that you need to add to your project's BuildConfig.groovy. 2) The Ivy cache location has changed. If you want to use the old location, configure the appropriate global setting (see below) but be aware that you may run into problems running Grails 1.3.x and 2.x projects side by side.

Comment: Thanks for tip! Will keep that in mind...I'm learning all the time